# `body.insertHtml` working incorrectly with list items

Tags: ms-word, office-js, cpu-word, word-web-addins

### Expected Behavior

I am trying to run this code:

```js
const html = '<ul><li>ListItem1</li><li>ListItem2</li><li>ListItem3</li></ul>';
body.insertHtml(html, Word.InsertLocation.end)
```

to expect:

[image: expected]

### Current Behavior

Somehow, the API doesn't detect the last list item.

[image: bug]

### Steps to Reproduce, or Live Example

Link to live example: [ScirptLab](https://gist.github.com/algomaster99/eb33a130196f8f5d8d8abc30dfd60882)

### Context

I am trying to render unordered lists in Word programmatically.

### Your Environment

- Platform [PC desktop, Mac, iOS, Office Online]: PC desktop
- Host [Excel, Word, PowerPoint, etc.]: Word
- Office version number: 18.2005.1191.0
- Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 1903

Comment: Have you tried to append any HTML elements? Does it help?

Comment: If you append `<br>` like this - `<ul><li>ListItem1</li><li>ListItem2</li><li>ListItem3</li></ul><br>`, it somehow works.

Comment: It seems we have just found the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You just need to append something to the end, for example, you may append `<br>` to the HTML string:

```
<ul><li>ListItem1</li><li>ListItem2</li><li>ListItem3</li></ul><br>
```

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a workaround. That's why I posted here to find a better approach.

Comment: There is no better approach I suppose.